# espressif setup: the install.bat file failed

Tags: installation

I'm using:

Windows 10 64
Python 2.7.16
Git 2.21.0
Cmake 3.15.1
Ninja 1.10.1
MConf V4.6.0.0-idf-20190628
Toolchain xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_2_0-esp32-2019r1-win32 (zip file)

To the PATH variable I added these paths:

C:\esp\cmake\bin

C:\Program Files\Git\bin

C:\Python27

C:\Python27\Scripts

C:\esp\toolchain\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin

C:\esp\mconf-v4.6.0.0-idf-20190628-win32

C:\esp\esp-idf\tools

C:\esp\cmake

I have created a new variable IDF_PATH with one path:

C:\esp\esp-idf

I have installed pip with python get-pip.py

When I'm running the install.bat file in the C:\esp\esp-idf order, I receive a failure (See image).[install.bat logdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zqry.png)

The first time I ran it. The zip file xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2020r3-win64 could not be extracted/read completely. Now it is skipped because it was already done. That's the reason why I can't show the logdata (had closed the DOS). Or does anyone have an idea how to reproduce it or to see the log data of a closed command prompt ?

According to these logdata I have to install Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0. So if I install it, that does not fix it, or I have a second problem.

Here the logdata after installing Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: esp-windows-curses, brotli
  Building wheel for esp-windows-curses (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for esp-windows-curses: filename=esp_windows_curses-0.1-py2-none-any.whl size=1186 sha256=f3d20e95c244846be0065eb4fb20dd2e0b0bfeb2b42bd3fb50487ccb37e77e80
  Stored in directory: c:\users\antoine schnetz\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\6b\23\dc\3f08e5d8e20335c3a015cb544ae35ed0220a6ef91fad289528
  Building wheel for brotli (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\antoin~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-0skvpo\\brotli\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\antoin~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-0skvpo\\brotli\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'c:\users\antoin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-wheel-bfvqex'
       cwd: c:\users\antoin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0skvpo\brotli\
  Complete output (93 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating bin
  creating bin\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  copying python\brotli.py -> bin\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  running build_ext
  building '_brotli' extension
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c\common
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c\dec
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c\enc
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/common/constants.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/constants.obj
  constants.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/common/context.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/context.obj
  context.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/common/dictionary.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/dictionary.obj
  dictionary.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/common/platform.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/platform.obj
  platform.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/common/transform.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/transform.obj
  transform.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/dec/bit_reader.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/dec/bit_reader.obj
  bit_reader.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/dec/decode.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/dec/decode.obj
  decode.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/dec/huffman.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/dec/huffman.obj
  huffman.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/dec/state.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/dec/state.obj
  state.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/backward_references.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/backward_references.obj
  backward_references.c
  c:\users\antoine schnetz\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0skvpo\brotli\c\enc\./find_match_length.h(34) : warning C4013: '_tzcnt_u64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/backward_references_hq.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/backward_references_hq.obj
  backward_references_hq.c
  c:\users\antoine schnetz\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0skvpo\brotli\c\enc\./find_match_length.h(34) : warning C4013: '_tzcnt_u64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/bit_cost.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/bit_cost.obj
  bit_cost.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/block_splitter.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/block_splitter.obj
  block_splitter.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/brotli_bit_stream.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/brotli_bit_stream.obj
  brotli_bit_stream.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/cluster.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/cluster.obj
  cluster.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/command.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/command.obj
  command.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/compress_fragment.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/compress_fragment.obj
  compress_fragment.c
  c:\users\antoine schnetz\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0skvpo\brotli\c\enc\./find_match_length.h(34) : warning C4013: '_tzcnt_u64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/compress_fragment_two_pass.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/compress_fragment_two_pass.obj
  compress_fragment_two_pass.c
  c:\users\antoine schnetz\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0skvpo\brotli\c\enc\./find_match_length.h(34) : warning C4013: '_tzcnt_u64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/dictionary_hash.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/dictionary_hash.obj
  dictionary_hash.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/encode.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/encode.obj
  encode.c
  c:\users\antoine schnetz\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0skvpo\brotli\c\enc\./find_match_length.h(34) : warning C4013: '_tzcnt_u64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/encoder_dict.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/encoder_dict.obj
  encoder_dict.c
  c:\users\antoine schnetz\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0skvpo\brotli\c\enc\./find_match_length.h(34) : warning C4013: '_tzcnt_u64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/entropy_encode.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/entropy_encode.obj
  entropy_encode.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/fast_log.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/fast_log.obj
  fast_log.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/histogram.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/histogram.obj
  histogram.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/literal_cost.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/literal_cost.obj
  literal_cost.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/memory.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/memory.obj
  memory.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/metablock.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/metablock.obj
  metablock.c
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/static_dict.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/static_dict.obj
  static_dict.c
  c:\users\antoine schnetz\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0skvpo\brotli\c\enc\./find_match_length.h(34) : warning C4013: '_tzcnt_u64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tcc/enc/utf8_util.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/utf8_util.obj
  utf8_util.c
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\python
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic/include "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\include" "-IC:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC" /Tppython/_brotli.cc /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\python/_brotli.obj /EHsc
  _brotli.cc
  C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\libs" "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Antoine Schnetz\.espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py2.7_env\PC\VS9.0\amd64" /EXPORT:init_brotli bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/constants.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/context.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/dictionary.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/platform.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common/transform.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/dec/bit_reader.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/dec/decode.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/dec/huffman.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/dec/state.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/backward_references.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/backward_references_hq.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/bit_cost.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/block_splitter.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/brotli_bit_stream.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/cluster.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/command.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/compress_fragment.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/compress_fragment_two_pass.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/dictionary_hash.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/encode.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/encoder_dict.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/entropy_encode.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/fast_log.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/histogram.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/literal_cost.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/memory.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/metablock.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/static_dict.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/enc/utf8_util.obj bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\python/_brotli.obj /OUT:bin\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_brotli.pyd /IMPLIB:bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common\_brotli.lib /MANIFESTFILE:bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common\_brotli.pyd.manifest
  _brotli.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'init_brotli' specified multiple times; using first specification
     Creating library bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common\_brotli.lib and object bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common\_brotli.exp
  encode.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
  static_dict.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
  backward_references.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64 referenced in function FindMatchLengthWithLimit
  backward_references_hq.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
  compress_fragment.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
  compress_fragment_two_pass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
  bin\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_brotli.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Antoine Schnetz\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for brotli
```

What am I doing wrong or what is missing on my computer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a recent issue in brotli, [see here](https://github.com/google/brotli/issues/848).

In the mean time you should be able to install an older version. I hit this today and found that 1.0.7 works for me.

```
python -m pip install --user brotli==1.0.7
```

Comment: Thank you ! But that did not fix the problem. The error is the same: Microsoft Visual C++ is required.

Comment: This is the version of VC I used in case that helps. Otherwise I'm afraid I don't have other ideas. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266